# Suggestion for an appropriate hash function

Tags: c, search, grep

I have two files (.txt) with phones numbers (one number per line). The files are pretty huge (282 MB), and I am writing a program to check these two files (raw data and DO NO CALL List), and filter out those numbers that does not exist in the DO NO CALL List. Something similar to grep -f raw.txt donotcall.txt -v > filtered.txt

I have implemented a very simple form of hashtable (separate addressing, using linked lists). My code currently, reads the phone numbers from the DoNotCall.txt and stores it in the hashtable. This is the function that I use to generate the hash. THE TABLE SIZE IS 100

```
int hashgen(char s[])
{
  int hash;

  hash = (s[0] + s[1] + s[2] + s[3]) * 100 / 13;
  return hash;
}
```

The hashtable: the way I did.

```
#define TABLESIZE 100
struct node {
char str[30];
struct node *next;
}
struct node *hashtble[TABLESIZE];

struct node *hashtable_alloc(void) //allocates space for a node in the memory
{
  struct node *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
  strcpy(tmp->str, "~"); //just a string to mark the head of the linked list
  tmp->next = NULL;
  return tmp;
}
void hashinit(void)
{
  struct node *t = NULL;
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    ht[i] = hashtable_alloc();
}
void hashtable_add(char s[])
{
    struct node *t = NULL;
    int arrnum = hashgen(s);

    t = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(t->str, s);
    t->next = ht[arrnum];

    ht[arrnum] = t;

}
```

Undoubtedly, I am a naive programmer dealing with hashtables. Please suggest me a better hash function. Though, I have read articles on hashtables, it would be great if anyone can tell me about a better approach, something better than hashtables, or do the hashtable method in a better way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using a database?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using C instead of Perl or Python?  They have hashtables built in and are designed for text processing.

Comment: That would be a nice idea. But, I wanted to learn the concept :)

Comment: Why not just sort the two lists and then use `comm`?

Comment: I'd use modulo-a-prime rather than integer-divided-by-a-prime... and I'd use a prime closer to your table size, so you aren't just wasting slots. Remember to allow for the possibility that two numbers have the same hash; you need some mechanism for retaining them all and searching through them (a second level of hashing and/or a set of results explicitly searched through). In general, you want your hash formula to be sensitive to order of the digits/characters so a simple swapped-characters typo doesn't yield an erroneous match. Consider performance as the number of entries gets large.

Comment: Concerning `hashgen` What is if your phone numer is longer than 4 characters ? Or worse shorter (e.g. 911)? `hashgen` should take into account all characters of the string.

Comment: @MichaelWalz : The phone numbers are of digits, but I am using the first four characters to calculate the hash, though, I am sure there is a better way to calculate hash. Thanks

Comment: @keshlam thanks for the suggestion. I will, very soon, change the function to use the modulo-a-prime, and I am using a linked list to store the elements that produces the same hash.

Comment: @twalberg : I can work out the sorting part, but I am not sure what is comm. Please tell me more about it.

Comment: @ShineJacob It's a utility for comparing the *comm*on lines in files. By default `comm file1 file2` shows three columns for the lines that are in `file1`, those in `file2`, and those in both, but it requires the input files to be sorted. Options like `-1`, `-2` and `-3` can be given to leave out the respective column. So, for example `comm -23 file1 file2` shows the lines that are only in `file1`. See `man comm` or search online for more details.